# How to view event log on UNIX

Tags: events

How to view event log on UNIX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check `/var/log/messages`, or the other files in `/var/log`.
- See kernel messages with the command `dmesg`.

Comment: Under `systemd` just use `journalctl -f`.